# Writing files to google app engine blobstore as the methods are going to be deprecated

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to save some data fetched from the web to blobstore, but the google doc says that

> Deprecated: The Files API feature used here to write files to Blobstore is going to be removed at some time in the future, in favor of writing files to Google Cloud Storage and using Blobstore to serve them.

The code in python is as follows

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from google.appengine.api import files

# Create the file
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')

# Open the file and write to it
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
  f.write('data')

# Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
files.finalize(file_name)

# Get the file's blob key
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
```

I am wondering if there is another way to write to blobstore instead of the official upload method.

Comment: Its the blobstore that is going away hence the api deprecation. Have you read the getting started on the could storage client librbry ?  Its has code that presents a file like api in the example.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted

Comment: I want to store the file in blobstore instead of cloud storage.

Comment: yes but blobstore is going away. You can continue to use it and the api until such time as the shut it down. Hence the deprecation

Comment: I haven't heard anything about blobstore going away, is there any official mention about this? @TimHoffman But yeah I don't think gsc client library supports writing to blobstore other than the deprecated files api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a file-like API, you have to go with GCS.

Blobstore is for uploading more-or-less static images and serving them.

If you want to write using a a file-like API and then serve from Blobstore, you can write to GCS and get a BlobKey to the file.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage

But writing to BlobStore like you want is deprecated.  Stop trying to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

An option may be to put the data in the datastore using a TextProperty